# SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 - Javascript errors in Firefox 19.0

Tags: 2011, cme

I have recently installed the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 CME and can successfully load and browse the content manager in IE8/9 without issues.

However, in Firefox version 19.0 I can see no items in the main content area (the frame on the right of the publications list).

I see the following error in the Error Console: (the error re occurs every time I click on a publication):

```
Error: InternalError: too much recursion
Source File: http://xxxxxxxx/WebUI/Editors/CME/Views/Dashboard/Dashboard_v6.1.0.55920.5_.aspx?mode=js
Line: 1
```

Has anyone experienced this kind of issue with Firefox and can anyone suggest a fix?

Many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you need hotfix CME_2011.1.1.83165. It's available from [www.sdltridionworld.com](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx) (login required.)

You will need to be on SP1+HR1 prior to installing this hotfix.

Comment: +1 and thanks for answering on Tridion Exchange. Has anyone made the "oh I see!" joke yet? :-)

Answer (score 10):

This was highlighted in the December Customer Support Newsletter for Firefox version 17 (but also affects the later versions) with the following:

> **SDL Tridion 2011 / Firefox 17**
>
> Changes in FireFox 17 can cause an infinite loop in the Tridion 2011
>   Content Manager Explorer. A hotfix has been released to resolve this
>   issue. The hotfixes are available for Tridion 2011 HR1 and Tridion
>   2011 SP1 HR1.
>
> The Tridion 2011 HR1 hotfix (CME_2011.0.1.83201) is downloadable from:
>   https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011/index.aspx
>
> Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 hotfix (CME_2011.1.1.83165) is downloadable from:
>   https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2011_SP1_1/index.aspx
>
> Both links require a login to SDLTridionWorld.com.

Hope this helps.